# Create actions off of collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create some actions dynamically, something like the below.

But as the code is not in a method I get the following error: "undefined local variable or method"

Is this at all possible, and if so - how?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  CATEGORIES = [:music,:movies,:art,:jokes,:friends,:whatever].freeze
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  Post::CATEGORIES.each do |category|
    eval <<-INDEX_LIKE_ACTIONS
      def #{category}
        @posts = Post.where( category: '#{category}' )
        render :index
      end
    INDEX_LIKE_ACTIONS
  end
end

resources :posts do
   collection do
     Post::CATEGORIES.each {|category| get category.to_s}
   end
end
```

Comment: I would question your need for separate method for each category if all you are doing is rendering the index view. If it is more complicated than that, then it might be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ruby's [define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method)

```
Post::CATEGORIES.each do |category|
  define_method category do
    @posts = Post.where(category: category.to_s)
    render :index
  end
end
```